# How do I finish a task on Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, task

I start an activity in a new task and I want to kill the task is when the user leaves it  because I think the task is useless when the user leaves.

How can I achieve this on Android? Setting the finishOnTaskLaunch attribute of the root activity has no effect.

Comment: Do you want to finish an activity or the app ( since you specified its the root activity)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the noHistory tag in the manifest , what you can also do is call finish() in onPause for that activity.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion,but it won't work.By the way,the activity is the root activity of a task.

Comment: I am very sorry. I misunderstand the problem. It may have nothing to do with task. What I want to do is to forward to another activity when invoking the activity from history list.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

make sure your onPause() looks like:

```
public void onPause(){
  super.onPause();
  finish();
}
```

Comment: How're you verifying that its not working? remember reclicking on the application is going to restart it, seems like a dumb question but I've been there, to close to the problem.